# Graduation date on internship applications?

Tags: job-search, internship

I'm a mechanical engineering undergrad student in the US, currently in 3rd year. 2 seperate university transfers have made it so I'm narrowly missing my intended 2025 graduation date, instead forced to take a full extra year (since I'm missing a single prerequisite for senior projects in the fall).

On my internship applications, I've been putting in 2025 as my graduation year, because I've heard that many systems automatically filter out sophomores and below for engineering internships. I figured I could explain it to the human interviewers after I get past the initial phase, since I still have the requisite coursework of a typical junior student.

Is this the right approach, or should I list my actual graduation date?

Answer (score 2):

At least in my circle of acquaintances, internships were very much an extended job interview. Sure, you learn a bit in the process. In some cases you might do something useful. But most of the time you're interviewing for a job. If you start a year early, when it comes time to hire, they'll have a cohort of people that worked there last year to choose from, plus you who worked there two years ago and then weren't available to hire when they expected. I think the odds are good they'll choose from the more recent group.

I think I'd be honest about your graduation date if it's a place you hope to work after school.